# Why is the canonical bundle 1 dimensional

Tags: geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

The canonical bundle is defined to a bundle of $n$-form, so how can it be one dimensional?

Comment: The manifold/variety has dimension $n$, so if you look at the dimension of the space of $n$-forms, you'll see that this space has dimension $1$ (think about the $n$-th exterior power of a vector space of dimension $n$).  You can think of the $n$-form on a point in an $n$-dimensional space as a measurement of volume at the point, and, at a point, all different ways of measuring volume are just scalings of each other.